# Update a table column with Value based on the same table fied

Tags: sql-server

I have the below table Structure.

**Order_Table**

```
Ord_ID  Ord_Date          Del_Date         Del_Qty  Del_Time  Hits  Miss

10001   9/13/2013 12:30   9/13/2013 13:10  2        40        2     0

10002   9/13/2013 13:09   9/13/2013 15:10  1        119       0     1

10003   9/13/2013 16:20   9/13/2013 16:50  1        30        1     0
```

I want to update the table **Del_Time** based on **(Ord_Date - Del_Date)**, **Hits** should populate with value of **Del_Qty** field if the **Del_Time** is less than **60** and **Miss** should be populated with value from **Del_Qty** if **Del_Time** is greater than 60.

Is this Possible? Am using MS Sql Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between two `datetime` values is a `datetime`.  It doesn't make sense to say "less than 60".  I think you want minutes (this is a guess).  If so, you want to use the `datediff()` function.

Otherwise, this is fairly simple `update` syntax, with a `case`.  The `case` is used to avoid updating values when the conditions are not met:

```
update order_table
    set del_time =  datediff(minute, del_date, ord_date),
        hits = (case when datediff(minute, del_date, ord_date) < 60
                     then del_qty else hits
                end),
        miss = (case when datediff(minute, del_date, ord_date) > 60
                     then del_qty else miss
                end)
```

Comment: Thank you Linoff, Your Solutio Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

or **(Edit)** do it in three statements:

```
UPDATE tbl SET del_time=datediff(minute,ord_date,del_date);
UPDATE tbl SET HITS=del_qty WHERE del_time<60;
UPDATE tbl SET MISS=del_qty WHERE del_time>60;
```

see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d1e3/1

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. Corrected it, but now I need three statements ... ;-(

Comment: I think you can do it int two statement.

Comment: UPDATE tbl SET HITS=del_qty,del_time=datediff(minute,ord_date,del_date) WHERE del_time<60;        
    UPDATE tbl SET MISS=del_qty,del_time=datediff(minute,ord_date,del_date) WHERE del_time>60;

Comment: Yeah, certainly true! In the end it is probably a matter of preference: the three statement version is probably slower on the SQL server but its code is probably easier to read/write/maintain.